# How to pass local private key to ssh command on intermediate jump server?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have an intermediate server between my local and my target server.

With password authentication I can ssh to the target like this:

```
ssh me@intermediate-server ssh me@target-server
```

But now both server works with key authentication.

How can I do something like this?

```
ssh me@intermediate-server ssh me@target-server -i /path/to/my-local-prv-key
```

The above command won't work of course because it looks for the key file on the intermediate-server.

So how to pass my private key to the final command safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, not this way.

But there's better way anyway, use the [`-J` (jump) switch](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J), instead of nesting the `ssh`.

```
ssh -J me@intermediate-server -i /path/to/my-local-prv-key me@target-server
```

The `-i` applies to both servers. But it should do no harm, if the key cannot be used on the `target-server`. If you need to use a different
key on each server, you can use two `-i` switches (`ssh` would then try both keys on both servers).

See also [Does OpenSSH support multihop login?](https://superuser.com/q/1488097/213663)